# JS CountDown no reload on refresh please

Tags: javascript

Well my code should be working but it isn't. Each time I reload the time, my Countdown start back at his initialised value.

Since I'm not familliar with JS you may be able to m'éclaircir the mind

```
<script>
  var upgradeTime = 172801;
var seconds = upgradeTime;
function timer() {
  var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
  var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
  var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
  var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
  var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
  var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
  function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
  }
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = pad(days) + ":" + pad(hours) + ":" + pad(minutes) + ":" + pad(remainingSeconds);
  if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Completed";
  } else {
    seconds--;
  }
}
var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()',1000,function() {
            secondPassed();
            if (seconds === 0) {
                eraseCookie(seconds);
            } else {
                createCookie(seconds, seconds, 7);
            }
        });
</script>
```

How do I call it

```
<h1>Server Release in : <span id="countdown" class="timer"></span></h1>
```

I just want my timer to not refresh each time you reload the page.
Any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: You have hardcoded upgradeTime, you should fetch upgradeTime from the server or read the value from cookie

Comment: Your `upgradeTime` is being used as the number of seconds until the end of the countdown.  So of course it will restart on a refresh.  You probably need a timestamp of *when* the upgrade needs to happen, and then subtract the current time to get the number of milliseconds for the countdown, and then do the calculations from that.  How you find that timestamp is an important issue, but for testing you can just hardcode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
var upgradeTime = 172801; //Timer length in ms
var timerMS = window.localStorage.getItem("date");
startTimer();

function timer() {
    var difference = timerMS - Date.now();
    if (difference <= 0) {
        startTimer();
        return;
    }
    var seconds = (difference / 1000).toFixed(0),
        days = Math.floor(seconds / 24 / 60 / 60),
        hoursLeft = Math.floor((seconds) - (days * 86400)),
        hours = Math.floor(hoursLeft / 3600),
        minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours * 3600)),
        minutes = Math.floor(minutesLeft / 60),
        remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

    function pad(n) {
        return (n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = pad(days) + ":" + pad(hours) + ":" + pad(minutes) + ":" + pad(remainingSeconds);
    setTimeout(timer, 1000);
}
function startTimer() {
    if (!timerMS || timerMS < Date.now()) {
        timerMS = Date.now() + upgradeTime;
        window.localStorage.setItem("date", timerMS);
    }
    timer();
}
```